# Using binary search to find the square root of a number in C

Tags: c, algorithm, math

Trying to work out the square root of a number using binary search, however my implementation of it is not working and i'm not sure why - any help appreciated, thank you

Heres my code. 'end' being the value of the number I want to be square rooted

```
 while(start <= end) {
   float mid = ((start + end) / 2);
   printf("\nhalving mid");

   if(mid * mid == end){
      sqrt = mid;
      printf("\nsqrt = %d", sqrt);
   }
   if(mid * mid < end){
     start = mid + 1;
     sqrt = mid; 
     printf("\nsqrt: %d", sqrt);
   }
   else{
     start = mid - 1;
   }
 }
```

Comment: What exactly is the input in your code snippet?

Comment: There is no input I'm using it as a square root function where 'end' is the number I want to find the square root of

Comment: Your code will print values smaller that the square root, continue past a direct hit, and get stuck in an endless loop. I'm sorry to have to tell you this, but you must tackle some simpler exercises before you attempt this.

Comment: If this isn't just for fun or training use a Newton iteration which converges much faster. (ignoring Math.sqrt for a moment).

Comment: Use a debugger or print the interval ends in every step to see why the dynamics of your implementation stall at some point. Going up by one, going down by one, repeat infinitely.

Answer (score 8):

In addition to the logic problems in your code, it is not a good practice to compare floating point numbers.

`mid * mid == end` will probably always fail, even for sqrt(9) because [it is very difficult to test floating-point numbers for equality](http://www.cs.yale.edu/homes/aspnes/pinewiki/C(2f)FloatingPoint.html).

Look at this implementation using a range (epsil) instead of comparison:

```
static float my_sqrt(float num)
{
    double start = 0.0;
    double end = num;
    double sqrt = 0.0;
    double epsil = 0.000001;

    while (start <= end)
    {
        double mid = ((start + end) / 2);

        sqrt = mid;
        printf("sqrt = %f\n", sqrt);
        if (fabs(mid * mid -num) <= epsil)
        {
            break;
        }
        else if (mid * mid < num)
        {
            start = mid;
        }
        else
        {
            end = mid;
        }
    }
    return sqrt;
}
```

Comment: Do you have a special reason for not using `DBL_EPSILON` from `float.h`?

Comment: the idea was to show that precision is in the programmer's hands. It sounds like a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

I am not fixingyour code, just explaining how I would write it.

Use an invariant that expresses the bracketing of the solution:

```
low² <= N < high²
```

Then taking an intermediate value `mid`, the test

```
mid² <= N
```

allows to choose among

```
low² <= N < mid² and mid² <= N < high²
```

and narrow down the search interval.

The iterations can stop when the search interval is a small as the floating-point representation allows (i.e. 23 bits for single precision). You can stop when `low == high`.

To establish the invariant,

```
low= 0, high= N
```

can do, provided that `0 <= N < N²`. This doesn't work when `N <= 1`. A quick and dirty workaround is to set `high= 1`.

```
low= 0
if N >= 1:
    high= N
else:
    high= 1

while low < high:
    mid= 0.5 * (low + high)
    if mid * mid <= N:
        high= mid
    else:
        low= mid
```

---

IMO, testing for equality `mid² == N`, then inequality `mid² < N` is counter-productive. You may be tempted to think that early termination when `N` is a perfect square allows to shorten the execution time. But in reality, most of the input numbers are not perfect squares and you will be performing two tests instead of one, making the program slower on average.

Answer (score 0):

Certainly the last line should be

```
 end = mid - 1;
```

conforming to the three cases

```
start..mid-1, mid, mid+1..end
```

---

And you should separate the number `num` that you want to compute the square root of and the end `end` of the search interval.

---

Of course you will also get a problem when the square root is not an integer. Then at some point it will fall inside one of the intervals `(mid-1, mid)` or `(mid, mid+1)` and thus outside of your algorithm.

Thus you need to separate the cases as

```
[start, mid] (mid, mid+1), [mid+1,end]
```

if you want to stay with integer boundaries. The middle case is

```
 ( mid*mid> num ) && ( (mid+1)*(mid+1) < num )
```

Comment: I've tried that before however it does not work when 'end' is the value of the number I want to find the square root for, I just get the value 1 returned every time

Comment: Of course you will get a problem when the square root is not an integer.

Comment: You will also get non-sensical results if you change the input during the algorithm. Separate the input that stays constant during the search from the variable ends of the search interval.

Answer (score 0):

You should replace your last line with

```
end = mid -1
```

in the else snippet

Answer (score -1):

```
public int sqrt(int x) {
    if (x == 0)
        return 0;
    int left = 1, right = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    while (true) {
        int mid = left + (right - left)/2;
        if (mid > x/mid) {
            right = mid - 1;
        } else {
            if (mid + 1 > x/(mid + 1))
                return mid;
            left = mid + 1;
        }
    }
}
```