# square root without pre-defined function in python

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.7

How can one find the square root of a number without using any pre-defined functions in python?

I need the main logic of how a square root of a program works. In general math we will do it using HCF but in programing, I am not able to find the logic.

Comment: Do you know how to find the square root of a number _on paper_? If you do, then you should be able to translate than logic to Python. There are several algorithms out there if you want to use those as guidelines.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding the square root using Newton's method (errors!)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12850100/finding-the-square-root-using-newtons-method-errors)

Comment: See also [Writing your own square root function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1623375/868044).

Comment: You could `x**0.5`... maybe that's cheating.

Comment: I need logic without using predefined function to find square root

Answer (score 6):

There is a famous mathematical method called **Newton–Raphson method** for finding successively better approximations to the roots.

Basically , this method takes initial value and then in successful iterations converges to the solution.You can read more about it [here](http://nptel.ac.in/courses/122104019/numerical-analysis/Rathish-kumar/ratish-1/f3node6.html).

Sample code is attached here for your reference.

```
def squareRoot(n):
    x=n
    y=1.000000 #iteration initialisation.
    e=0.000001 #accuracy after decimal place.
    while x-y > e:
        x=(x+y)/2
        y=n/x
    print x

n = input('enter the number : ') 
squareRoot(n)
```

Here you can increase the accuracy of square root result by adding '0' digits in e and y after decimal place.

Also there are other methods like binary search for finding square roots like shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40849402/using-binary-search-to-find-the-square-root-of-a-number-in-c).

Answer (score 3):

here is the way you can get square root without using any inbuilt function of python.

```
def findSqrt(n):
    sqrtNum = n / 2
    temp = 0

    while sqrtNum != temp:
        temp = sqrtNum
        sqrtNum = (n / temp + temp) / 2

    return sqrtNum
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
def sqrt(n):
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        if (n % i == 0) and (i * i == n):
            return i
            break
```

Basically the program run for loop from 1 to n, then check if n % i = 0 and i squared = n, if true - return i and break.

Answer (score 1):

**square root without pre-defined function in python**

```
a=eval(input("Enter a number to see the squareroot:"))
b=0
x=(1+a/1)/2
while b!=10:
    b+=1
    x=(x+a/x)/2
print(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would approach this by building an algorithm that gives a precise guess because these steps are easy to understand and can be repeated until very accurate. For example:

- Build in the known perfect squares (2^2 is 4, 4^2 is 16, etc.)
- Find which perfect squares the given number lies between (if given 10, it lies between 3^2 (9) and 4^2 (16)). Therefore, the square root of 10 is somewhere between 3 and 4.

Check out [this link for an easy explanation](http://www.math.com/school/subject1/lessons/S1U1L9DP.html) of this algorithm and how to repeat to ensure accuracy.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way you can do it. Note that it is not the most mathematically efficient way it is just an easy way to do it without messing with weird mathematics:

```
a=int(input('number! '))
accuracy=10 #number of decimals
s=0
step=1
for i in range(accuracy+1):
    while (s+step)**2<=a:
        s+=step
    step=step/10
s=format(s,'.'+str(accuracy)+'f')
print(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

The following python implementation is based on [C++ implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19611407/759298). The code does not directly use sqrt but uses `math.frexp` and `math.ldexp` to calculate the sqrt. This algorithms are like any other is good for  training. It is better to use `math.sqrt` in professional settings since the function uses direct [Intel instruction](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/sqrtss) or [ARM64 instruction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41799956/performance-of-sqrt-function-on-aarch64).

```
import math
def sqrt(n):
    if n < 0:
        raise ArithmeticError()
    n, exp = math.frexp(n)
    if (exp & 1):
        exp -= 1
        n *= 2
    y = (1 + n) / 2
    z = 0
    while (y != z):
        z = y
        y = ( y + n/y) / 2
    return math.ldexp(y, int(exp/2))


import unittest

class TestSqrt(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_simple(self):
        self.assertEqual(sqrt(4), math.sqrt(4))

    def test_various(self):
        l = [4, 9, 64, 49, 39499, 48484]
        for i in l:
            self.assertEqual(sqrt(i), math.sqrt(i))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```