# How to find the nearest square root to nearest using binary search using python

Tags: python

How to find the nearest square root of number?

- If square root present then I need the exact square toot, otherwise the previous of square root.

Example is below:

- `squre_root(101) = 10`
- `squre_root(100) = 10`

Approach

- Find the mid number of square root to find
- for `101`: find the mid, that is `51`
- since `51 * 51 <= 101` then `51` will be divided by half
- Like at last by binary search I will get `10`

Sample Code :

```
def find_sqrt(k):
    begin, last = 1, k
    mid = int((begin + last)/ 2)
    
    while begin < mid:
        if mid * mid => k:
            mid = int(mid/ 2)
        if mid * mid <= k:
            mid += 1
    return mid
```

I had found [guess nearest square root in python](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/guess-nearest-square-root-in-python) while researching.

Comment: i have gone through https://www.tutorialspoint.com/guess-nearest-square-root-in-python

Comment: ```51 * 51 <= 101```?

Comment: I think this is similar to [Newton's Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method#Square_root).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46183020/square-root-without-pre-defined-function-in-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have translated the psuedo-code from [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/guess-nearest-square-root-in-python)

```py
def find_sqrt(k):
    begin, last = 1, k

    while begin < last:
        mid = int((begin + last) / 2)
        if mid * mid <= k:
            begin = mid + 1
        else:
            last = mid
    return begin - 1


print(find_sqrt(100))
print(find_sqrt(101))
```

Comment: But what did you change? Please explain the changes

Comment: begin - 1, i did not get, can you explain